# insert data into a sql table using PDO_SQLSRV with php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, phpmyadmin

This is my code to insert  data into a sql table. using pdo_sqlsrv driver with php.
Can any one please help me out whether my code has any kind of errors. Whether the code written by me is perfect or whether it has any flaws in it.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <?php

    include("config.php");

     if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
       {
         $serverName = "testserver.com";
        $uid = "sa";
        $pwd = "ams";
        $database = "Test";
        try {
        $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=$serverName;database=$database", $uid, $pwd);
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY , true);



$sql="INSERT INTO  header ([date]
      ,[isfnameandaddress]
      ,[contactname]
      ,[contacttelephone]
      ,[contactemail]
      ,[containernumbers]
      ,[vesselname/voyagenumber]
      ,[estimatedateofdeparture]
      ,[estimateddateofarrival]
      ,[billoflandingnumber]
      ,[recordnumber]
      ,[consigneenumber]
      ,[sellernameandaddress]
      ,[buyernameandaddress]
      ,[shiptopartyameandaddress]
      ,[manufacturer]
      ,[containerstuffinglocationnameandaddress]
      ,[consolidaternameandaddress])
        values( null,                   '$_POST[date]','$_POST[address1]','$_POST[contactname]','_POST[telephone]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[conatainernumbers]',
'$_POST[vesselname]','$_POST[departuredate]','$_POST[arrivaldate]',$_POST[ladingnumber]','$_POST[importerrecordnumber]','$_POST[consigneenumber]',
'$_POST[sellernameandaddress]','$_POST[address2]',$_POST[address3]','$_POST[address4]','$_POST[address5]','$_POST[address6]')";

 $results = $conn->query( $sql );

} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();

}
}
?>
```

Comment: Holy mother of injections. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Sorry....may you can share me any link where can i get them.

Comment: Sure [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) you go.

Comment: thank you very much Andrew i am waiting for your link...:)

Comment: I did link it man, it's in the above comment. Just click the "here". You can make words links by using []() such as [ Google ]( www.google.com ). Without the spaces.

Comment: i couldnt get you even a single word what you are talking about